# The css for a particular div I have is not working

Tags: html, css

I had some css displayed for a div which was working, however since adding other elements and adding unrelated code the css is no longer applying to it's relative div.

```css
 #container
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #ffffe6;
  border-style: solid;
  border: 2px, black;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="functions"></div>

  <div id="roll">
    included elements
  </div>
  
  <div id="keyboard" class="center">

  SOME PHP

  </div>
</div><!--closing tag for keyboard div-->

</div><!--closing tag for container div-->
```

The css for the container code doesnt seem to be registering despite it working a few saves ago. I can not seem to work out why or how it now isnt picking it up and displaying it in the browser window.

Comment: The snippet seems to work fine except for the extra closing div. What exactly isn't  working?

Comment: Im not sure if this is the problem, but your closing tags don’t match up with your comments. You have one extra div closing tag. The one you commented as closing the keyboard div is closing #container, and the div closing tag after that is unmatched.

Comment: The closing tag for keyboard div is closing the container div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You have an extra closing div tag



    <div id="container">
      <div id="functions"></div>

      <div id="roll">
        included elements
      </div>
      
      <div id="keyboard" class="center">

      SOME PHP

      </div><!--closing tag for keyboard div-->
    </div><!--closing tag for container div-->
```